# Heating Hydrogen to produce Microwave EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, hydrogen

I was reading that exciting a hydrogen atom to a certain point will force lower energy electrons to jump temporarily to high-energy/valence states. These electrons immediately return to the lower energy state and in the process, emit an EM pulse at 2.45 Ghz while the process continues. It also  emits visible light.

I also read that at a temperature of about 51 C(121 F), that a full liter of hydrogen will reach this state. There are other ways but this example is extremely straightforward.

*Question:* Does that mean that hydrogen excited in this way will begin emitting incoherent microwave EM frequencies? Can I use my home microwave leak-detector on beaker of heated hydrogen gas just plucked from electrolysis and get a reading? If I had a copper coil near, would I register a voltage/magnetic field?

I am scared to experiment as my last name is not Hindenburg but I see tons of applications for communications.

Comment: Re “I was reading”: a link might be helpful. Your description is different from my understanding of hydrogen spectroscopy, but that’s not quite my field.

Comment: Maybe your source was about hydrogen plasma in a microwave field of 2.45 GHz? Atomic hydrogen does not have emission line in this range. At least not for the most common spectral series.

Answer (score 3):

The microwave radiation you have been reading about is emitted by [black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) not by electronic transitions in atoms. This type of radiation is produced by oscillating dipoles, and these are the result of thermal vibrations in solids and liquids. However these do not occur in gases, or at least not under normal circumstances. I discussed this in my answer to [Blackbody or characteristic emission of radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222092/blackbody-or-characteristic-emission-of-radiation).

So your litre of hydrogen gas will not emit any microwaves because it's a gas not a solid or liquid. But do solids and liquids emit microwaves at room temperature? And the answer is that yes they do, but not at any significant intensity. The spectrum of black body radiation is described by [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) and at room temperature the emission peaks at around $10\mu\text{m}$ i.e. in the infrared. The intensity of radiation emitted at microwave wavelengths is so small as to be effectively zero.

Comment: Here is the most condensed version of what I started with. It did not mention what form the hydrogen had taken (such as ice, liquid, vapor, plasma). It merely says "Hydrogen Atom" in "some state":

"....Thus, in a hydrogen atom (composed of an orbiting electron bound to a nucleus of one proton), an excitation energy of 10.2 electron volts is required to promote the electron from its ground state to the first excited state. A different excitation energy (12.1 electron volts) is needed to raise the electron from its ground state to the second excited state. "

Comment: @ClancyJohn yes, but the electronic excitations you describe don't produce microwave radiation

Answer (score -1):

I asked this question in regards to the theory(theory?) that the Great Pyramid at Giza was designed as such a device. In the "Queens Chamber" was found residue of zinc chloride/aluminum chloride and sulfuric acid that was poured in to the northern and southern shafts to mix there. The H2 gas produced in this reaction would rise through the quartz rock and collect in the King's Chamber where it is concentrated and excited by a low frequency hydraulic pulse. This vibrated the whole structure to rhythm of Nile river water being pumped beneath the Queen's chamber.

Also found in the King's chamber were small hollowed cavities that continue to the surface out of the pyramid. These cavities are dimensioned perfectly as waveguides for a 2.45 Ghz microwave stream--the energy release in EM for n-2 to n-1 electron drop in hydrogen. These microwave "guns" point at interesting points in the sky--Orion's belt and the star, Sirius B, for starters. Engineers say the output is on the order of 20 MW. This is not a question about UFOs though.

It must all be bunk as from this forum, I have learned that exciting electrons in hydrogen--n=1 to 2 to 1-- cannot be done with hydraulic pumps generating heat.  Certainly not in this way.  Maybe they used the power as electromagnets for camels, elephants, and starving slaves cannot lift 10 ton rocks.

Maybe if they dig out they newly found room above the grand gallery and twice the size of the King's chamber, we will find the control console...if Horus allows:)

Anyway, my question is **answered**. Thank you!